# playframework 2.X JPA to MSSQL Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.2

I want to using JPA connect to MSSQL,using sample computer-database-jpa can access h2 sql ,but when i change to mssql ,it's put a error message "PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defaultPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory" who can help me thanks!

my application.conf

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;DatabaseName=TCGW;SelectMethod=cursor:sendStringAsUnicode=true"
db.default.user=qqqq
db.default.password=qqqq
#db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
#db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
applyEvolutions.default=true
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
```

my persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" >
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
     <!--     

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
    -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```